# git pull fails with "Untracked working tree file 'blah' would be overwritten by merge", but tree is clean

Tags: git

I've checked in some changes to my local repository that I want to push, but when I do a git pull, I get:

```
paul$ git pull
```

> error: Untracked working tree file 'documentation/Android/SwiftKey/buttons.xcf' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting

My working tree contains no untracked files:

```
paul$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 2 and 26 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

The commits that I've made do not touch the file that it's complaining about.

I've read answers suggesting that I do a `git reset HEAD --hard`, but I'm not sure what effect that will have on the commits that I've made?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not the commits you've made that touch the file, but the commits that you're pulling. Inspect the remote branch you're tracking to see what's happened. For example, `git log master..origin/master` will show all the commits that have happened on *origin/master* since you last pulled. According to your output above, there are 26 of these. Using the `--name-status` option will show which commit added the file.

You will need to rename the offending file, do the pull, and then move it back (overwriting the copy from the repo). `git diff filename` will then tell you how your copy differs from the one that someone else has committed to master. You can then commit the differences, or throw them away with `git checkout filename`.

You will need to use `git pull --rebase` to rebase your recent commits on top of the ones in `origin`. Once `git status` says master is *ahead* rather than *diverged* from origin/master, you can push.

Comment: Thanks Neil - just before I received your answer, I managed to work out that the problem was that the "Swiftkey" directory had been renamed "SwiftKey" by another user. Because OSX's file system isn't case sensitive, that's what was causing my problem :-(

Comment: For the record, I overcame the problem by removing that portion of my local tree (safe, because none of my changes touched it), then doing git pull followed by checkout -- on the tree I previously deleted.

Eugh.

Comment: Case insensitivity can be the source of a lot of problems. I've had the same thing with svn and it can be hard to spot what's going on.

I tried using a case-sensitive root volume on my Mac at one time, but lots of applications broke. Adobe CS, in particular, refuses to install to a case-sensitive volume, and the company refuses to fix their applications.

Comment: This can happen even if you make no commits on your master branch. The fix is still the same, though.

Comment: what do you mean by 'offending' file. Are all those 26 files offending?

Comment: @SunilSharma There are 26 *commits*, not 26 files. By offending file I mean the one that git is complaining about, which in this case is called `documentation/Android/SwiftKey/buttons.xcf`. That file needs to be moved out of the way while doing a pull, then restored, then checked to see if its differences need to be kept.